# Setting initial state from Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have stored username, full name & email address in redux store. I have a component that needs the email address so it can make an API call to obtain the users group information (using domain - i.e chase@gmail.com becomes the key for the database query using gmail.com). The component is connected to the store and uses mapStateToProps to obtain state information.

Is it an anti-pattern to do something like this in this.stat = { }

```
this.state = {
  group: '',
  owner: this.props.user.id,
  domain: this.props.user.email.split('@')[1],
  errors: {},
}
```

Thank you for all the suggestions.

Comment: Not a good idea. Use redux state directly in the render method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Its not good practice to duplicate redux state in the local state.**

Why? Because it is not scalable. Imagine if you r data will be need to change. So you will need to update both your local state and redux state. And also, if your redux state will change - you need to update local state. It will becomes to spaghetti.

---

What you can do?

You can just use only your data from props. Implement `shouldComponentUpdate` method to be sure, that your data will be always up-to-date.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.props.user !== nextProps.user
}
```

And use the data from the props.

Comment: Thanks again @DmitriyKovalenko

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use them based on my thumb rule.

If you need the data be instance specific - `use state`.
Example: you have a button group component, keep the data in state since there is a possibility of multiple usage of the component.

If your data is required to be global, so that anyone can modify it from any other component, and specially if you want the data to be tied in to an external source, use Redux state. Since the data is external to your component, it becomes damn simple to manage it.

Link: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287

Comment: "It is always recommended to use Redux over React's internal state". No it isn't. The opposite should be true. If you have are storing internal states that are just there for that component then their is no reason to make it global. Just like if you have global and private variables in JS, if you can make it private you do that.

Comment: That was what I infer from lots of discussions that I read. But those are still opinions, so my opening line was wrong. Edited the answer.